# Threadpool C++ 11 game engine

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool, stdthread

It's time to implement a threadpool in my game engine with **std::mutex**, **std::condition_variable**, **std::unique_lock** and **std::lock_guard**.
I have read a lot about Lock-free Programming, but that seems really hard to get it right. The number of jobs I need to execute each frame is approx. 40-200.
So, I have couple of questions that needs to be answered before I do any attempts to implement this stuff.

How many threads should the threadpool contain? 
As many as the number of cores on the CPU? And if this is the case, should I create nrThreadsThreadPool = nrCpuCores - 1(main thread)?

Example:

- Current computer: 4 cores, 4 threads.
- Threadpool contains 3 threads.

Let's say that I have 17500 objects in an array and I need to perform frustum culling on each object.
Should I send 5000, 5000, 5000 as three jobs to the threadpool and perform 2500 in the main thread? 
This solution seems to be non-optimal, because each frustum culling test will take different amount of time to complete, and this can result in cores that has nothing to do.
Or, should I create a work size variable with a size of 512 or something similar, and calculate the number of jobs that I need to send to the threadpool?

```
threadpool.push(job_0, arrayStart_0, arrayEnd_0) //512 frustum culling.
threadpool.push(job_1, arrayStart_1, arrayEnd_1) //512 frustum culling.
threadpool.push(job_2, arrayStart_2, arrayEnd_2) //512 frustum culling.
threadpool.push(job_3, arrayStart_3, arrayEnd_3) //512 frustum culling.
...
threadpool.push(job_n-1, arrayStart_n-1, arrayEnd_n-1) //512 frustum culling.
mainThreadFrustumCulling() //The main thread should execute the remaining frustum culling tests.
threadpool.wait() //Wait for frustum culling to finish in the thread pool.
doSomethingWithTheResults()
```

The job size should be enough to outweigh the overhead of locking/unlocking with std::mutex.

Comment: Looks to me like something that needs to be done on the GPU and not the CPU. Usually games have very few threads running (main, sound, render, AI, etc), and leave the heavy graphics duties to the GPU.

Comment: That will lead to synchronizing issues, i.e. reading back data from GPU to CPU. We want to reduce the draw calls. I have other heavy stuff that can be parallelized on the CPU, and that stuff must be executed on the CPU.

Comment: In my experience, these kind of optimizations are machine specific, and require a bit of trial and error experimentation with the numbers. Also, you are probably doing these things all the time, maybe get rid of the overhead of the pool and just have dedicated threads. My suggestion is that you get the game working, even slowly, before optimizing

Comment: If you don't have any IO, socket, disk read, etc sort of stuff, there is (AFAIK) no point having more threads than cores, or 2x cores if your system has hyper-threading. If you have a lot of stuff where a process is waiting on the system without using the CPU (like any of the examples I gave above), then more threads will help. Probably just best to write a good benchmark though and tweak the size of the thread pool by that. Though, if you plan to run this code on other machines, the optimal number may be different there.

Comment: You should consider using an OcTree/quadtree if you need to do so much culling. Generally cullign doesnt seem to be a good job to be performed multi-threaded. It just introducec synchronization issues and lag as you need to wait for the culling to complete on each thread until you can finally render the objects.

Comment: Slides from dice: http://www.frostbite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CullingTheBattlefield.pdf. They used a linear array + parallel brute force frustum culling, and it worked much better than their old system with trees. I'm going to borrow some ideas from here: http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3_bfg/threading.php